# Can I get help in making Visual Basic Excel macro for converting Morse code to English language and vice versa

Tags: excel, vba, decode, converters, morse-code

I need help in making VB Excel macro that would take input from InputBox and convert it from English to Morse and vice versa, then show result in MessageBox. I've been stuck, and I've got no clue how could I make it. Thanks for help in advance <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### English to Morse Code

- Although this is almost by default done with a [`Dictionary object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object), I stuck with the arrays as an interesting alternative.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function getMorseCode( _
    ByVal s As String, _
    Optional ByVal CharDelimiter As String = " ", _
    Optional ByVal WordDelimiter As String = vbLf, _
    Optional ByVal NotFoundReplacement As String = "~") _
As String
    
    Dim CharsList As String
    CharsList = _
        "a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|" _
        & "k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|" _
        & "u|v|w|x|y|z|" _
        & "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|" _
        & ".|,|?|:|/|""|'|;|!|" _
        & "(|)|&|=|+|-|_|$|@|" _
        & " "
    Dim CodesList As String
    CodesList = _
        ".-|-...|-.-.|-..|.|..-.|--.|....|..|.---|" _
        & "-.-|.-..|--|-.|---|.--.|--.-|.-.|...|-|" _
        & "..-|...-|.--|-..-|-.--|--..|" _
        & "-----|.----|..---|...--|....-|.....|-....|--...|---..|----.|" _
        & ".-.-.-|--..--|..--..|---...|-..-.|.-..-.|.----.|-.-.-.|-.-.--|" _
        & "-.--.|-.--.-|.-...|-...-|.-.-.|-....-|..--.-|...-..-|.--.-.|" _
        & WordDelimiter
    
    Dim Chars() As String: Chars = Split(CharsList, "|")
    'Debug.Print Join(Chars, vbLf)
    Dim Codes() As String: Codes = Split(CodesList, "|")
    'Debug.Print Join(Codes, vbLf)

    Dim CurrentMatch As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim cChar As String
    Dim Result As String
    
    For n = 1 To Len(s)
        cChar = Mid(s, n, 1)
        CurrentMatch = Application.Match(cChar, Chars, 0)
        If IsNumeric(CurrentMatch) Then
            Result = Result & CharDelimiter & Codes(CurrentMatch - 1)
        Else
            Result = Result & CharDelimiter & NotFoundReplacement
        End If
    Next n
    ' Remove leading Char Delimiter.
    Result = Right(Result, Len(Result) - Len(CharDelimiter))
    ' Remove Char Delimiter following a Word Delimiter.
    getMorseCode = Replace(Result, WordDelimiter & CharDelimiter, WordDelimiter)
 
End Function

Sub TESTgetMorseCode()
    MsgBox getMorseCode("""The character '%' cannot be found!""")
    'Debug.Print getMorseCode("""The character '%' cannot be found!""")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother, it works flawlessly, I've got one more question, may you please just rotate script for converting from Morse to English (I'm real bad in VB but I need this haha) . Thanks! <3

Comment: This only returns FALSE for me.. The Function Arguments window shows the correct result, but the cell only displays FALSE. I've enabled macros and searched for other causes. What else could I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following (just for your reference - you may need to convert the codes to VBA, but I believe you can do it )

```
   If txtInput.Text = "a" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "b" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-..."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "c" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-.-."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "d" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-.."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "e" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "f" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "..-."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "g" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "--."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "h" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "...."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "i" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "j" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".---"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "k" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-.-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "l" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".-.."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "m" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "--"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "n" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "o" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "---"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "p" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".--."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "q" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "--.-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "r" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".-."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "s" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "..."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "t" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "u" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "..-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "v" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "...-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "w" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".--"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "x" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-..-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "y" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-.--"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "z" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "--.."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "0" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-----"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "1" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = ".----"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "2" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "..---"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "3" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "...--"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "4" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "....-"
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "5" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "....."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "6" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "-...."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "7" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "--..."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "8" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "---.."
        End If
    If txtInput.Text = "9" Then
    lblStatus.Caption = "----."
    
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try to make it tomorrow morning. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Have a great day